# How to develop python remotely on 2 different machines using PyCharm

Tags: python, synchronization, pycharm, workflow

I am currently working on a server API.  Said API is used in a mobile app that is being developed, and thus I've set up a dev server on a VPS.  The API server uses python/django/django-rest-framework.

I have two offices that I work at- one has my desktop workstation, and at the other I use a laptop.  I commonly will move from one office to the other during the day.

I have followed the many tutorials that are out there for setting up PyCharm to use a remote interpreter, and to sync changes to a remote server.  However this seems to be causing a bit of an issue for me- I have 3 different copies of my code that may or may not be synced.  Specifically, the server will always have its code synced with the last machine to have updated files.  For example:

1. Make a change to `coolStuff.py` using my desktop.  Save the changes.  This pushes the saved changes to the server via pyCharm.
2. Get called to the other office.  Drive over, open up my laptop.  Go to edit `coolStuff.py`, and not realize that I am now working on an old copy,  potentially overwriting the changes I made in step 1.

To get around this, I've been committing all of my changes after step 1, then pushing them up to the repo.  I then need to pull the changes to the laptop.  However, there are times that the push or pull is forgotten, and issues arise.

Is there a better workflow, or tools within pyCharm that can automate a 2-way sync between a dev machine and the server?  Alternatively, would it be bad practice to use a cloud storage/sync to keep everything syncd up?  (e.g.- store my code directory on something like Dropbox or OneDrive).  I figure there has got to be a better way.

Comment: Are you using github ?

Comment: No, I am using a self-hosted git-lab server for revision control.